# How to prevent ubuntu installation from ejecting cd-rom?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, kvm-virtualization

I'm installing ubuntu server 10.04 over kvm switch. I have no physical access to the server. The server has ubuntu installation cd inserted. How to prevent setup from ejecting it after completion?

Comment: If it doesn't eject, then how do you plan on booting the installed OS?  Why do you need the disk in the machine after the install is done?

Comment: I'll set up boot order in the BIOS. I need it for possible reinstallation.

Comment: I see, you really shouldn't need it to reinstall.  After the `/boot` partition is created and grub is installed you could simply drop an [mini iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) in `/boot` and configure grub to boot off that, assuming a somewhat recent version of grub.

Comment: And what to do if boot record is corrupted? I can always boot from cd in recovery mode.

Comment: I guess that is possible, but that sure seems like it would be extremely rare.  I have never seen that happen with grub, except with the hard drive or some other system component was also failing.

Comment: Put tape over the CD drive?  Or, got remote hands?  Just need it jammed back in there once..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit ejecting your CD is probably `/etc/init.d/casper` (look for the line with `eject` on it).
Modify your casper script not to do that and the CD should remain in the drive.

(You will need to `remastersys` or cut a new boot CD some other way in order to make this change permanent...)

Comment: (Yeah - it took me that long to get around to putting in an Ububtu disk and looking for the script with "eject" in it. It's one of ***those*** days at the office...)

Answer (score 0):

Closing the rack-door should probably be enough. The tray will meet resistance while not fully open and should close again. Poor server that has no iLo or RAC capable of inserting iso-images, though.

Comment: this assumes a tray-loading drive that is powered through the full length of travel.  Most of the rack-mounted servers I have seen have trays that "pop" but don't extend (so the tray is "out" in that the CD isn't loaded/usable, but the tray is only extended maybe 1-2cm)

Comment: Mine is exactly like this. it cannot retract automatically (like in notebooks)